# Mapping to a composite unique (not primary) key in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes - USER and ROLE. There are corresponding tables in the database, and a table called USER_ROLE that links the two.

USER has a primary key on column "**id**", and a composite unique key on columns "**realm**" and "**realm_user_id**". ROLE has a primary key on column "**role_id**"

USER_ROLE has 3 columns - **role_id**, **realm**, **realm_user_id**.

**role_id** references **role_id** in the ROLE table, and (**realm,realm_user_id**) reference the composite key in USER. I don't have access to the DB, so I can't update the schema.

There is a many-to-many relationship between users and roles. I want to be able to call getRoles() on User, and getUsers() on Role.

class User:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="USER")
    public class User {

        ..other fields..

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Role.class)
        @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", 
        joinColumns = { 
          @JoinColumn(name = "realm", nullable = false, updatable = false),
          @JoinColumn(name = "realm_user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
        private Set<Role> roles;
```

Class Role:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE},
        targetEntity=User.class
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
    inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="realm",nullable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="realm_user_id",nullable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Set<User> users;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
A Foreign key refering User from Role has the wrong number of column. should be 1
```

I tried creating a separate class containing realm and realm_user_id, referenced in the **@IdClass** annotation, but that failed as User already has a primary key on **id**. I tried using the mappedBy annotation, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try the *@Embeddable* and *@Embedded* annotations? http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-embeddable-embedded-hibernate-annotation

Comment: I moved realm and realm_user_id to a @Embeddable class. Now I'm getting a "referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property" error.

Comment: Can you then check if this answer works for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/14514276/861403?

Comment: Nope, same error as the one mentioned in the question