# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames referencing not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

I ran into the below exception while mapping a one-to-one between 2 entities. The 1 first entity has embedded composite key. The second entity also has embedded composite key. The tables are part of legacy system. Data is flat, relations are not well defined. Please help.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(FLAG_NAME) of net.javabeat.spring.model.ReferralsM.mnEditFlag referencing net.javabeat.spring.model.MnEditFlag not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1440)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1727)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 34 more
```

Here is my one to one mapping in the main/parent table.

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = MnEditFlag.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "REFFLG", referencedColumnName = "FLAG_NAME", insertable = false,     updatable = false)
MnEditFlag mnEditFlag;
```

Answer (score 25):

The cause of the issue is that you are trying to use a single join column, while the identity of the referenced entity is defined by multiple columns. You simply have to define all the needed join colums and you are good to go:

```
@JoinColumns({
   @JoinColumn(name = "REFFLG", referencedColumnName = "FLAG_NAME"),
   @JoinColumn(name = "OTHER_KEY", referencedColumnName = "SOME_OTHER_NAME"))
   ...
})
MnEditFlag mnEditFlag;
```

OT: you should not need the `targetEntity` attribute on the `OneToOne` annotation. This is already defined by the type of the target entity: `MnEditFlag`. You probably need `targetEntity` only for untyped `Collections`.

EDIT: If there is a single join column, which is only part of the PK and you cannot change the existing tables, perhaps you can define a new join table with all necessary columns.

Then you define the join table to be used for the relationship:

```
@JoinTable(name="ReferralsM_MnEditFlag",
  joinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name="REFERRALS_ID1", referencedColumnName="ID1"),
    @JoinColumn(name="REFERRALS_ID2", referencedColumnName="ID2")
  }, inverseJoinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name="REFFLG", referencedColumnName="FLAG_NAME"),
    @JoinColumn(name="REFFLG2", referencedColumnName="FLAG_NAME2")
})  
MnEditFlag mnEditFlag;
```

You would have to migrate the data to the new join table programmatically or by queries.

Unfortunately you cannot define a relationship with a partial PK with vanilla JPA, perhaps Hibernate has such a feature, like one-to-one by query, but I cannot confirm it.

EDIT2: The join table should contain **all PK columns for both entities** to be fully functional. That is why I have defined two join columns for each side in my example. The number of columns and their names are purely exemplary.

Extracting only the one join column you already have in your table would not add any value.

The optimal solution would be to change the entity tables so they define a proper relationship between the entities. It is sufficient to change only one of the tables and define it as the owning side as you did, but with **all FK columns**. This would require a migration effort, since you would need to add the data for the missing FK columns like described above.

EDIT3: The strategies I recommended were based on the assubmption that you want to have complete CRUD functionality. If you just want to pull the data for display or reporting, a view is perfectly fine. You can define the columns you need and map the whole view to a single entity. However, as it is a view, you will not be able to change the data or migrate it.

Comment: Thanks kostja. Looks like my edits were not saved/updated. I saw similar response on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206000/hibernate-referencedcolumnnames-not-mapped-to-a-single-property. The 2nd table (child table) has composite primary key of 2 columns. Of the 2 columns, One column's data matches with data of first table. The second column is completely different. So, I am not sure how I can join more than 1 column. That's why I added just one column on the one2one join.

Comment: The tables are part of a legacy system. Data is flat. Preferrably I would like to find a way without adding/editing 2nd table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you are suggesting is to create a new table for storing the one common key (column) between the 2 tables into a new table. Is that right? However I did not get the syntax though. Why 2 join columns, specially the second one for REFERRALS_ID2 and REFFLG2? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I will also check with my dba if it is an option to add a new primary key to table 1 and 2 and nicely define foreign key relation;                 will check if it is possible to add composite keys of table 1 to table 2.

Comment: Modifying the existing table would be best, please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks. My requirement is just to pull the data. Can I use a database view instead of 2 tables?

Comment: This could in fact make the matter simpler. Please see the edit. It think we are close to a solution. At least there are not much alternatives left :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch kostja. I will give that a try for now and will work with our DBA to either alter the tables or creating a new one.  Does changing the Entity type from Hibernate to JPA would help? I will also look into reading the data into a Value Object (composite of required fields from Table 1 and 2) instead of an entity. I guess that would limit me to just fetch the data, I may not be able to do crud operations on a Value Object.

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck :) Changing from Hibernate to JPA would not change much, since you are only using JPA-conforming annotations in the code parts I have seen. Using VO/DTO is a valid option as well, but as you noticed yourself - it is a one-way street, as with the view - there is no putting tha values back into the database (except you use native SQL or bulk updates, but lets not get into that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use targetEntity on @ManyToOne. The targetEntity should be equal to the parent (probably abstract) class.
The temporary solution is here depending to your class hierarchy: 
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4975