# Using Hibernate to map flat legacy tables with NO foreign key / Composite key relation

Tags: hibernate, orm, relational-database, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to define a mapping between two Entities in a legacy DB using Hibernate annotations. Entities under consideration DOES NOT SHARE a foreign key/ composite key and at this point of time, modifying the legacy tables is not a possible option :(

The entities are similar to the below;

[image]

If you look at the table, they DON'T MAINTAIN ANY FOREIGN KEY RELATION and don't share an identical composite key too, the only common factors are the columns zip_code and school_name. I would like to define my Entity class corresponding to SCHOOL using HIBERNATE ANNOTATIONS in such a way that each time an entity of school is retrieved from DB, I would also like to get all teachers associated to that school. I have been trying to achieve this referring to examples of one-to-many, secondary-tables, join-tables, but all of them demands to either have foreign-key relation or shared composite-id relation.

Please help me design an one to many relation between School and teachers using the common columns "school name" and "zip code".

Comment: Did you notice that actually, you haven't asked any real question ?

Comment: Erwin- I just edited my post and added a question. I am looking for help to design an one to many relation between School and teachers using the common columns "school name" and "zip code".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any foreign key to map an association using JPA. All you need is to reference the appropriate columns, and their referenced column, in the association mapping:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="SCHOOL_NAME", referencedColumnName="NAME"),
    @JoinColumn(name="SCHOOL_ZIP", referencedColumnName="ZIP_CODE")
})
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```

or, if you want the association to be bidirectional:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="school")
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="SCHOOL_NAME", referencedColumnName="NAME"),
    @JoinColumn(name="SCHOOL_ZIP", referencedColumnName="ZIP_CODE")
})
private School school;
```

Whether there is a foreign key constraint or not is irrelevant to Hibernate. Just don't expect it to be work flawlessly if some teacher references an unknown school name or zip code, which is what the foreign key constraint allows preventing.

Comment: Tried a 1-many (unidirectional) as described in your response, but got this exception;    failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(SCHOOL_NAME, SCHOOL_ZIP) of edu.Teacher.teachers referencing edu.School not mapped to a single property.    I searched online to check this and was directed to posts which mentions that a table join can be done only when the @JoinColumns includes all columns which are part of the composite key of entity School.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536095/org-hibernate-annotationexception-referencedcolumnnames-referencing-not-mapped

Comment: Apologies first- for late reply and thanks much for your input on this.    Still looking at ways to overcome this issue - appreciate your valuable inputs on this.