# Hibernate unidirectional @OneToMany association triggers updates of foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "TYPE")
public class Type implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 563398089758359222L;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "OBJECT_TYPE")
  private String objectType;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TypeNameId")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "TypeNameId", sequenceName = "SQ_TNAME_WL", allocationSize = 1)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @ToString.Include
  private String code;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "BOUND_TO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  @JoinColumn(name = "BOUND_TO_CLASS", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_TYPE")
  private Set<Translation> translations;

}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "TRANSLATION")
public class Translation implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4974947078465122824L;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "OBJECT_TYPE")
  private String objectType;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TranslationId")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "TranslationId", sequenceName = "SQ_LTRANSLATION_WL", allocationSize = 1)
  private Long id;

  @Size(max = 4000)
  @Column(name = "VALUE")
  private String value;

  @Size(max = 150)
  @Column(name = "LOCALE")
  private String locale;


  @Size(max = 150)
  @Column(name = "BOUND_TO_CLASS")
  private String boundToClass;

  @Column(name = "BOUND_TO_ID")
  private Long boundToId;

}
```

Other entities may also have their translations in Translations table but do not include mappings with respect to Translation entity.
When creating a Type with translations, Hibernate wants to do the SQL below:

Hibernate: insert into type (code,  object_type, id) values ("code","Type", 1)

Hibernate: insert into translation (bound_to_class, bound_to_id, locale, object_type, value, id) values (null, null, "en_US", "Translation", "American code", 2)

There is a non-deferrable unique constraint on the columns bound_to_id, bound_to_class and locale. It is not possible to create translations in the same locale for different types since bound_to_class and bound_to_id are null in Hibernate SQL.

How do I change the mappings to allow translation creations without making the unique constraint deferrable or using bidirectional association?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen vs what is happening now? You are inserting a new Type and associating it to an existing Translation instance, but specified the foreign keys are within the Translation table - so the only way to persist this relationship is to update the Translation table. This mapping seems wrong to me, as it means a translation can only belong to one Type, and if that is the case, why would it exist outside of the Type (which has cascade all and orphan removal set to true). If you don't want this update statement, don't set the Type->Translation relationship

Comment: @Chris I edited the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: So you need the values put in as part of the insert statement for 'Translation'.  While different providers have different options -Translation has no tie to Type, and a flush can happen at any time, so the only way to really force this data to go in within the same or single Translation  insert statement is to tie FK modifications to the Translation entity itself. I don't know why you wouldn't have added the Translation->Type mapping, or some other basic mapping for the FK value that you can set and control yourself (within Transaction of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than setting up a bi-directional relationship:

```
public class Type {
  ..
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="type", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Translation> translations;
}
..
public class Translation {
  ..
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "BOUND_TO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  @JoinColumn(name = "BOUND_TO_CLASS", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_TYPE")
  Type type;
}
```

Which would then setup the fk values for you, the alternative is to map the BOUND_TO_ID and BOUND_TO_CLASS within the Translation yourself, and pull them yourself from any Type instances:

```
public class Translation {
  ..
  @Column(name = "BOUND_TO_CLASS")
  private String objectType;

  @Column(name = "BOUND_TO_ID")
  private Long objectId;

}
```

You'd then need to mark the relationship within Type as read-only:

```
public class Type {
  ..
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "BOUND_TO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable=false, insertable=false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "BOUND_TO_CLASS", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_TYPE", updatable=false, insertable=false)
  private Set<Translation> translations;
}
```

Since the Type id is generated, you'd need to call persist on Type first, flush the context to make sure the ID is assigned, and then use the ID and objectType to set any Transaction instances you wished to create to point to it.

Comment: Thank you Chris! Suppose I use bidirectional mapping for Type and Translations, How do I do the same for Currency entity and Translation? I asked this question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018824/org-hibernate-annotationexception-not-mapped-to-a-single-property